# ExtJs: What will be the sequence of code execution in ajax call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, asynchronous, single-threaded

Given the fact that Javascript is a single-threaded language, what would be the sequence of execution in the following code in ExtJs?

```
FuncA();

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    params: {
        id: 1
    },
    success: function(response){

        FuncB();
    }
});

FuncC();

FuncD();
```

Here would the sequence of execution of functions be A-C-D-B?

Or

Is it ever possible that FuncB() gets called prior to FuncC() or FuncD()? If yes, then in which conditions?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order will always be A-C-D-B unless the ajax request is synchronous, but it's not really recommended to use that since it causes the UI to hang.

For example, try this (in Chrome, preferably)

```
function f1() {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        s += 'a';
    }
}

function f2() {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
        s += 'b';
    }
}

Ext.require('Ext.Ajax');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var d;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data.json',
        success: function(){
            console.log('finished');
        }
    });

    d = new Date();
    f1();
    console.log(new Date() - d, 'f1 done');
    d = new Date();
    f2();
    console.log(new Date() - d, 'f2 done');

});
```

You will see that even though it takes around 1s to run the code, the ajax request always fires last, even though the request itself only takes around 7ms (it's a local box). Then try it again by commenting out the calls to f1/f2.

Comment: What if C function takes long time? What if Ajax call takes very little time?

Comment: It doesn't matter. There is at least some delay in making an Ajax request, whereas the C & D methods will always execute synchronously & thus won't release a "lock" until they complete.

Comment: In other words: B is put into a new call stack, while C and D are on the same stack as A. Each stack is always fully processed before the next can start.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli: I am in full agreement with you. Carried out similar tests and got the same result. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A
{B}
C
{B}
D
{B}

b can execute at all the positions marked {b}. but will be executed only once.
edit:-
no javascript isnt a multi threaded language. so maintains a `queue` of the code to be executed. so when it reaches `funcC` it starts executing `FuncC` and then after ii returns looks for next function to be executed in the queue which might be `funcB`(if the ajax request is completed) so `funcB` can only be executed in between 2 functions calls

Comment: Thanks for the post Parv. So does it all depend upon the completion of Ajax request? And if this is the case, then will the execution abruptly jumps to success of ajax function and start executing FuncB(); as soon as the ajax is completed?

Comment: @ParvSharma: Agreed with Evan. B() would always be executed only once C() and D() are done.

Answer (score -1):

Please note that the javascript code runs top to bottom. So in this case, your code execution will start at `funcA()` and ends at `funcD()` but `funcB()` can be called anytime because it totally depends upon how soon `ajax.php` returns the response.

Comment: B() would always be executed in the last only and never before C() or D() in any case. Thanks for the time though.